# Does it makes sense to permit only root to use ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, root

i have a question about some "security":

What would happen in the worst case if the root has the permission to 
use the ssh tunel?

Maybe it its better to use sudo instead of an root account?

As a "ssh" newbwie i want to ask you.

Thank you

Comment: I agree with @mickey in that `root` should have no SSH access to begin with. Beyond that, things depend entirely on your use case and what might be an appropriate configuration for one situation will not work at all in a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, privileged users, especially `root`, should not be able to access the server via SSH. An open port listening to incoming connections is one extra point of failure and should the login be compromised, you've essentially given up control of your server.

[sudo](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) is a much better way of allowing temporary privileged command execution for non-privileged users.

I would strongly advise disabling password authentication and using [SSH keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-debian-9) instead.